# Not Able to Retrieve data using core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I am using coredata in my application to store data.i have to add the data in one view controller and retrieve it in another view controller.i tried the following code but it is not working.

```
//addViewController.m

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{

   CoreDataOneAppDelegate  *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
   NSManagedObject *newContact;
   newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];
   [newContact setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
   [newContact setValue:amount.text forKey:@"amount"];
   name.text = @"";
   amount.text = @"";
//label
  status.text = @"saved";
  NSError *error;
  [context save:&error];
}
```

I want to retrieve the values and display them in a tableView

```
//retrieveViewController.m

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    objects = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    CoreDataOneAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" 
            inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSError *error;
    objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request 
                                 error:&error];
   [request release];
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

//tableView

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return  [objects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 11, 110, 21)];
labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 11, 70, 21)];


static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
}

[cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];

 NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
 matches = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[matches valueForKey:@"name"]];        
    labelOne.text = str1;
    NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[matches valueForKey:@"amount"]];        
    labelTwo.text = str2;

return cell;
}
```

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.i tried using NSZombieEnabled and i got the following error.

```
2012-04-27 11:59:18.153 CoreDataOne[4370:207] *** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5931e40
```

i am able to retrieve the values if write the code what i have written in viewDidLoad in cellForRowAtIndexPath but how to declare the numberOfRows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not using ARC.  I think you need to retain the result of your fetch request in viewDidLoad (don't forget to release it in dealloc).  Also, you are leaking by alloc/initing an array and then overwriting it.

Comment: I am new to xcode and coredata.can you please provide me some code or any link which helps me?

Comment: @Chandubhai My answer is not Core Data related.  It is a memory management issue.  Do you know how Obj-C memory management works?  If not, then you should thoroughly read about it before you continue with anything.  [retain] and [release] are the slightly dated way of doing it.

Comment: ok sure! will do it.and also can u please tell how can i make the above code work?

Comment: It is just a guess, but try adding a `retain` message to the end of your executeFetchRequest line.  Then in your `dealloc` function, add `[objects release]`

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in MutableArray in view didload where you are retrieving values. And then use it in your table view. Declare the noof Rows as array count.

Comment: changing it to a MutableArray is giving me an error at this line ... objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request 
                                 error:&error];